# google cse custom search daterestrict

Tags: google-custom-search

I'd like to limit the search results for my custom search engine (cse) to one day.

I found some info on a "dateRestrict" parameter here
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/reference/cse/list

It is also available in the api explorer
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/customsearch/v1/search.cse.list

How can i pass this parameter to the search options? I've been trying to put them wherever i thought it might work but to no avail...

i found similar questions already but the answer was just to switch to a different api....

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    google.load('search', '1', {language: 'de', style: google.loader.themes.V2_DEFAULT});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
      var customSearchOptions = {};
      customSearchOptions[google.search.Search.RESTRICT_EXTENDED_ARGS] ={'as_sitesearch' : 'https://xy.com/'};
      var orderByOptions = {};
      orderByOptions['keys'] = [{label: 'Relevanz', key: ''} , {label: 'Datum', key: 'date'}];
      customSearchOptions['enableOrderBy'] = true;
      customSearchOptions['orderByOptions'] = orderByOptions;
      var customSearchControl =   new google.search.CustomSearchControl('mykeygoeshere', customSearchOptions);
      customSearchControl.setResultSetSize( google.search.Search.FILTERED_CSE_RESULTSET );
      customSearchControl.setLinkTarget( google.search.Search.LINK_TARGET_SELF );
      var options = new google.search.DrawOptions();
      var query = unescape(LTH.getUrlVars().searchfor);
      customSearchControl.draw('cse', options);          
      customSearchControl.execute(query);                    
    }, true);
  </script>**strong text**
```

Answer (score 0):

Options to the arguments passed to cse can be specified in the customSearchOptions. I tried this before but the parameter names are DIFFERENT THAN IN THE XML-API (thanks google)

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/js/cselement-reference#opt_options

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/xml_results#WebSearch_Query_Parameter_Definitions

so this finally worked

```
    customSearchOptions[google.search.Search.RESTRICT_EXTENDED_ARGS] ={'as_sitesearch' : 'https://www.landestheater-linz.at/','as_qdr':'d100'};
```